# find the white/ black pixels in specific region javacv

Tags: javacv

I have tried this code. 540 is the left most x value of the box,3 is left most y value of the box,262 - width ,23 -height of the region which I am going to calculate the ratio of the white/black pixels. What I really wanted to do is detect the number of white/black pixel ratio in a specific region.I have calculate the coordinates for each cell (regions which I am going to specified)and try with this code.But the error in counting.

Can I please have an idea about this issue please..

I am really stuck here with my final year project.

```
     CvSize cvSize = cvSize(img.width(), img.height());

     IplImage image = cvCreateImage(cvSize, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
     IplImage image2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);

     cvCvtColor(image2, image, CV_RGB2GRAY);
     cvSetImageROI(image2, cvRect(540,3,262,23));
     //IplImage image2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);

    //
     //cvCvtColor(arg0, arg1, arg2)
    // cvCvtColor(image2, image, CV_RGB2GRAY);      
     //cvThreshold(image, image, 128, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);





    CvLineIterator iterator = new CvLineIterator();
    double sum = 0, green_sum = 0, red_sum = 0;
    CvPoint p2 =  new CvPoint(802,3);
    CvPoint p1 =  new CvPoint(540,26);

    int lineCount = cvInitLineIterator(image2, p1, p2, iterator, 8, 0 );



         for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)  {
             sum += iterator.ptr().get() & 0xFF;
         }
          System.out.println("sum................"+sum);        
         CV_NEXT_LINE_POINT(iterator);

    }


}
```

it gave the result as sum................0.0

I have really stuck with this..can you please give any solution for this issue please

Answer (score 0):

Move `CV_NEXT_LINE_POINT(iterator);` line inside the `for` loop. Then it should work.